# Cleancode: try/catch in Promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, coding-style, es6-promise

I am working on redux-form atm and found the piece of code. Its working for me but is there any cleaner way to write this in ES6 style?

```
const asyncValidate = (values/* , dispatch */) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      if (['john', 'paul', 'george', 'ringo'].includes(values.name)) {
        const error = {
          name: 'That username is taken'
        };
        throw error;
      }
      resolve();
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  });
};
```

I would appreciate your help

---

### Solution

```
const asyncValidate = (values/* , dispatch */) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const errors = {};
    if (['john', 'paul', 'george', 'ringo'].includes(values.name)) {
      errors.name = 'That username is taken';
    }
    reject(errors);
  });
};
```

probably cleaner way?!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`try`/`catch` is redundant in promise chains and promise executor functions.

Any error thrown is automatically converted to a rejection of the promise you're supposed to return. The promise code calling your function takes care of this. So just do:

```
const asyncValidate = values => new Promise(resolve => {
  if (['john', 'paul', 'george', 'ringo'].includes(values.name)) {
    throw { name: 'That username is taken'};
  }
  resolve();
});
```

and it gets converted to a rejection.

Comment: good explanation! Any unhandled exception inside a promise constructor is automatically wrapped inside a rejected promise. This is also true for the newly created promises inside a then() which makes it easy to just use throw() inside. (see [25.4.1.3.2 in ES6 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-resolve-functions))

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to simplify `if-statement`, also you don't need a catch block here:

```
//ES5
const asyncValidate = (values) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ['john', 'paul', 'george', 'ringo'].includes(values.name) ? reject({ name: 'That username is taken' }) : resolve();
    });
};

//ES6 - using "generators"
const asyncValidate = function* (values) {
    return yield ['john', 'paul', 'george', 'ringo'].includes(values.name) ? Promise.reject('That username is taken') : Promise.resolve();
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work for me:
"Uncaught Error: asyncValidate function passed to reduxForm must return a promise"

Comment: Returning a generator of promises is not the same as returning a promise?! Maybe what you meant was an ES8 `async function`.