# How to properly handle reject in Promises

Tags: javascript, promise

We have this function in our code that is used to log in a user

```
const userLogin = loginData => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const res = await auth.post("/login", loginData);
      resolve(res);
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
};
// Calling function
const loginSubmit = async values => {
  try {
    const res = await userLogin(values);
    console.info(res);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Catch: ", error);
  }
};
```

But from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41540641/12101852), `try-catch` blocks are redundant in Promises. I wanted to try and clean this code, so I changed the code above into:

```
const userLogin = loginData => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const res = await auth.post("/login", loginData);
    if (res.status !== 201) {
      reject(new Error("Error"));
    }
    resolve(res);
  });
};
```

However, when I tried to login with incorrect credentials, the console logs an `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400`

I'm not really familiar with creating my own promises, so I don't know how to do this properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of problems in your code:

- You are unnecessarily creating a promise; `auth.post(..)` already returns a promise, so you don't need to create a promise yourself and wrap `auth.post(...)` inside a promise constructor.
- Another problem in your code is that executor function (function passed to the promise constructor) is marked as `async`; it [should not be an async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43083696/cant-throw-error-from-within-an-async-promise-executor-function).

Your function could be re-written as:

```
const userLogin = async (loginData) => {
    const res = await auth.post("/login", loginData);
    
    if (res.status !== 201) {
      throw new Error("Error"));
    }

    return res;
};
```

You could also re-write your function as:

```
const userLogin = async (loginData) => {
    return auth.post("/login", loginData);       
};
```

Don't forget to use the `catch` in the code that calls this function.

You might want to read the following article to understand whether you need the `try-catch` block: [await vs return vs return await](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/await-vs-return-vs-return-await/)

Comment: Thank you for the additional information!

Answer (score -1):

I think that in your case since you call to async function inside the constructor of the promise you need to use try catch.
The answer you referred is correct as long as the error happened while you are in the constructor (i.e. the Promise object is in the making), however in your case the rejection of the `auth` function happens long after the Promise was constructed and therefore it is not rejecting it.

BTW - You don't have to `await` in the promise. You may do the following:

```
const userLogin = loginData => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const prom = auth.post("/login", loginData)
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status !== 201) {
          reject(new Error("Error"));
        }
        resolve(res);
      });
    resolve(prom);
  });
};
```

Since you `resolve` the async `auth` call, any rejection by the `auth` call will be reflect as a rejection from you function